# How can we connect AWS userpool with DynamoDb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am currently using AWS cognito for user authentication. Now i want to store partial information of the users in the user pool to DynamoDb table. Is there a way to relate Userpool data with DynamoDb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can federate user pool with Cognito identity and get the scoped temporary credentials, you can use these credentials to connect to DynamoDB. This part of developer guide talks about this integration. [integrating user pools with identity pools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html)